# JQuery Horizontal Draggable ruler not smooth

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating a horizontal draggable ruler using jQuery UI. I have coded everything as expected but the dragging is not smooth.

When I try to drag the ruler in between the numbers, the drag is not working. The dragging works only when dragging the upper side of the ruler.

The image below shows the sections that are not draggable
[image]

I would appreciate if someone would explain or help me to get the whole ruler draggable

This is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function stripHTML( text ){
    // please do not edit this function
    var data = $("<div/>").html(text).text();
    return data;
  }

  $(function() {


    load_steps();

  function getVal() {
    var p = $(".weight-ladder").position().left;
    var r = "";
    //var h = $(".step").height();
    // the ruler starts at position 160
    // the difference between is 12
    // x= 20, 160, 148

    var difference = 160 - p;
    var per_section = Math.ceil(difference/12);
    r = per_section  + 20
    if( p < -7 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1;
    }

    if( p < -172 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1;
    }

    if( p < -326 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1;
    }

    if( p < -497 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;
    }

    if( p < -673 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1;
    }


    if( p < -855 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1009 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1155 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1325 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1504 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1682 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -1829 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }


    if( p < -2030 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -2175 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -2343 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -2513 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -2679 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }


    if( p < -2838 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -3028 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }


    if( p < -3186 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -3365 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -3533 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -3679 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -3869 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -4037 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

    if( p < -4181 ){
      r = per_section  + 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    }

   

    


   

    

     // console.log(  p );


    return r;
  }

  //$(".ladder").css()

  $(".weight-ladder").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    scroll: true,
    //containment: [0, -771, 150, 149],
    //containment: [0, -1148, 150, 60],
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      $(".ladder-value-input").html(getVal());
     
      $(".weight-value").html( "<span>"+getVal()+"</span> lbs" );
      

    }
  });


  function load_steps(){
    var main_steps = ""; 
    for(var i = 20; i <= 420; i ++){
      // i = 20, i = 21 bra bra bra bar
      var num ; 

      if( i == 20 ){
         main_steps += "<div class='main-step'><span>"+i+"</span></div>";
         for( var j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
            main_steps += "<span class='sub-step'></span>";
         }
      } else {
        if( i%5 == 0 ){
           main_steps += "<div class='main-step'><span>"+i+"</span></div>";
           for( var j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
              main_steps += "<span class='sub-step'></span>";
           }
        }
      }

      
      
       
    }

    $(".weight-ladder").html(""+main_steps+"");
  }

 
});

</script>


<style type="text/css">
  body{
    padding: 100px;
  }

  .weight-everything-holder{
    position: relative;
  }

  .horizontal-ladder{
    height: 100px; 
    overflow: visible;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }


  

  .weight-ladder{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    user-select: none;
  }

  .horizontal-ladder .main-step{
    width: 48px;
    border-left: 2px solid #979797;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .ui-widget-content{
    border: none;
  }

  .sub-step{
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #979797;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .main-step span{
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 50px;
  }

  .weight-marker{
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.65);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 170px;
    top: -50;
  }

  .weight-value{
    position: absolute;; 
    left: 120px;
    background: #475665;
    width: 70px; 
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: -80px;
  }

  .weight-value span{
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .weight-value:after{
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 12px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 12px solid #475665; 
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 39px;
  }
</style>

<div class="weight-everything-holder">
  <div class="ui-widget horizontal-ladder">
    <div class="ui-widget-content weight-ladder" style="left: -1631px;  flex: 1 0 150px;"> 

      <!-- starting horizontal ruler --> 



      <!-- ending the horizontal ruler --> 
    </div>
    <div class="weight-marker"></div>

  </div>
  <div class='weight-value'><span>180</span> lbs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: see whichever dragging effect or ease in effect you want in jQuery
https://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: It seems that the whitespace between the ticks is not being read as part of the `weight-ladder` element. When I inspect that element, I hit the `horizontal-ladder` element. When I inspect the `weight-ladder` element, it's only 300 x 100 and it's not appearing on screen currently, it's at the begging of the ladder. When a child object is dragged, it does move it. I think you need to make the Width of `weight-ladder` match your entire ladder to address the issue.